# Automatically run Java app after installation (Mac)

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, javafx, installation

Apologies if this has been asked already and I've missed it.

I'm writing a JavaFX desktop app, and would like to make it automatically run after installation, but I'm not sure where to look to make this happen (or even if it's possible?). I have successfully created a .dmg installer using E(fx)clipse & Ant. Are there options I'm overlooking which I can use in the build.xml? or am I looking in the wrong place entirely?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Perhaps this [shell script to package java code as a native OS X application](https://gist.github.com/jewelsea/5018976) may help you - I used something similar for internal development of a project to automate building testing of building, deploying and running a self-contained Java application.  Perhaps you could adapt concepts to invoke the `open -a AppName` command automatically by executing a script once the dmg file is installed (though I don't have the exact technique on how you would do that adaptation).

Comment: Thanks! I'll see if I can tweak this to do it :)